# Looking for Methodology to solving these conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

**What is the best method to follow when solving this kind of problem? Is there a technique to dissecting these problems, by using Venn Diagrams for instance? Or is the only way to compute the expressions**

Let $A,B,C$  be events relating to the experiment of rolling a pair of dice.

$1)$  If $P(A|C)>P(B|C)$ and $P(A|\bar{C})>P(B|\bar{C})$ either prove that $P(A)>P(B)$ or give a counterexample by defining events $A,B,C$ for which it is not true.

$2)$ If $P(A|C)>P(A|\bar{C})$ and $P(B|\bar{C})>P(B|\bar{C})$ either prove that $P(A)>P(B)$ or give a counterexample by defining events $A,B,C$ for which it is not true.

**Please note I am not looking for the answers, I am looking for the    "How-To" answer.**

Comment: We have $\Pr(X)=\Pr(X|Y)\Pr(Y)+\Pr(X|\bar{Y})\Pr(\bar{Y})$ (law of total probability).

Comment: What happens if you multiply both sides of $P(A|C) > P(B|C)$ by $P(C)? What happens if you multiply both sides of $P(A|\bar{C}) > P(B|\bar{C})$ by $P(\bar{C})? Now, add the inequalities and note $P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap \bar{C}) = P(A \cap (C \cup \bar{C})) = P(A)$.